# How can I call getsockopt in Java to get SO_ORIGINAL_DST

Tags: java, getsockopt

Does anyone know if there's an existing library out there that will allow me to make a call to getsockopt to get the destination IP for a socket that iptables has rerouted through my Java application?

[Here's a similar question](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/netty-users/2011-June/004618.html) on the Netty mailing list that went unanswered.

The call in c would look something like:

```
getsockopt(ctx->client.fd, SOL_IP, 
    SO_ORIGINAL_DST, &SANY_ADDR(addr), &SANY_LEN(addr))
```

Example of how to do it with JNI also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in Java. You could do it in JNI exactly as you have written, if you can get the socket FD, which is in the `SocketImpl` of the `Socket`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in Java . However you can add a request header param which store the original_dst. So you can use it from http header when you need.